# Custom alertDialog with listview android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, customdialog

How to make a custom AlertDialog in listView format and each listItem must contain a image and textview.

There is a intent passing on clicking of individual listItem.

How to do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Dialog innerDialog = new Dialog(context);
innerDialog.setTitle("Title");
innerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
```

Add custom list to alert Layout and you can find views by innerDialog.findViewById()

Comment: I got the dialog. How to show this dialog in dropdown format.?

Comment: I dont understand your question

Comment: I got a part of solution.
Dialog menuAleart = new Dialog(this);
menuAleart.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
alert layout contain both an Image and textview.
But, now my problem is- using xml we can show dialog as drop down format. how to do this using java code.?